# Problems finding a Lyapunov function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

I've been trying to find the Lyapunov function for the following system,

$\dot x= x^{2}-x-y$, $\dot y=x$.

Since Ive tried all typical ones, and some variations I havent been able to conclude that the derivative of the function is $<0$. The main question, I guess, is how to face the problem of finding a Lyapunov function when some term is even, which is the case of $\dot x$.

Probably there is a clever way to find this kind of functions and for sure Im missing it so, any help would be incredibly appreciated <3

Comment: All kinds of $ax^{2n}+bx^{2n}$(not ALL but lots haha), some $(ax+by+c)^{2}+dy^{2}+e$ and some others which I've been adapting according the derivatives I got haha :/ I dont know a better way to find them :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equilibrium of this system is not globally asymptotically stable:

[image: stream plot]

so there is no "global" Lyapunov function. A "local" Lyapunov function can be found by
linearizing the original system. The linearized system is
$$\dot x= -x-y,$$
$$\dot y=x$$
or
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}\dot x\\\dot y\end{array}\right)=
A \left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right),
$$
where
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{rr}-1&-1\\1&0
\end{array}\right).
$$
Solving the Lyapunov equation $A^TP+PA=-Q$, where $P$ is an unknown matrix,
$Q$ is any positive-definite matrix, one can obtain the solution $P$,
which can be used to construct the Lyapunov function
$$
V(x,y)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}x&y\end{array}\right)
P
\left(\begin{array}{r}x\\y
\end{array}\right).
$$
**Update begin**

$V$ obtained in this way is not only a Lyapunov function for the linearized system $$\tag{1}\dot x=Ax,$$ but for the original system $$\tag{2}\dot x= f(x)$$ too. Indeed, the original system can be written as $$\tag{2a}\dot x=Ax+\alpha(x)\|x\|,$$
where $\lim_{x\to 0}\alpha(x)=0$. The directional derivative
$$
\dot V\Big|_{(2a)}= (Ax + \alpha (x)\|x\|)^T Px+x^T P(Ax + \alpha (x)\|x\|)
$$
$$
            =x^T(A^T P+ PA)x + 2x^T P\alpha (x)\|x\|=
            -x^T Qx + 2x^T P\alpha (x)\|x\|.
$$
The inequality
$$
      x^T Qx \geq \lambda_{\min}(Q)\|x\|^2,
$$
where $\lambda_{\min}(Q)$ is the minimum eigenvalue of $Q$,
implies
$$
\dot V\Big|_{(2a)}\leq -\lambda_{\min}(Q)\|x\|^2+
              \Big|2x^T P\alpha (x)\|x\|\Big|
          \leq  -\lambda_{\min}(Q)\|x\|^2+ 2\|\alpha (x)\|\cdot\|P\|\cdot\|x\|^2
$$
$$
=\|x\|^2 \left( -\lambda_{\min}(Q)+2\|\alpha (x)\|\cdot\|P\| \right).
$$
Now notice that $\|\alpha (x)\|$ can be made arbitrarily small in some neighborhood of the origin because $\lim_{x\to 0}\alpha(x)=0$, hence, $\dot V\Big|_{(2a)}$ is negative definite.

This is actually a part of the proof of the indirect Lyapunov method.

**Update end**

For example, if we take
$$
Q=\left(\begin{array}{rr}2&0\\0&2
\end{array}\right),
$$
we obtain $V(x,y)=2x^2+2xy+3y^2$.

Comment: Thanks so much for your clear answer, but what was the intuition behind the application of the Lyapunov equation? Why did you think in that?

Comment: @user1trill I have updated the answer

Comment: Amazing answer dude! Thanks so much <3

Comment: I just checked the V(x,y) and unfortunately $\dot V = 4x \dot x + 2y \dot x +2 x \dot y + 6 y \dot y = 4x^{3} - 2x^{2}+2yx^{2}-2y^{2}$ when I evaluate the \dot x and \dot y of the original system. So, the function is not conclusive :/ any idea where Im wrong? Thanks so much

Comment: @user1trill Nothing is wrong, this is correct. The "local" Lyapunov function does not have to have a negative derivative everywhere, the derivative should be negative only in some neighborhood of zero

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer again and sorry to bother you even more but, im having some real troubles with this stuff haha, so, what should be the rigorous way to prove that is negative in that neighborhood? :/

Comment: @user1trill The proof for the general case is given in my answer and it is completely rigorous. If you want а proof for your specific system, consider $\dot V= -2(x^2+y^2)\left(1-\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}(2x+y)\right)$ and use the inequality $\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\le 1$.