# Lyapunov Function for system with $f(x,y) = x' = \sin y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, lyapunov-functions

I have the system

$x'=\sin y = f(x,y)$

$y'=-2x-3y = g(x,y)$

I am given the Lyapunov function $V(x,y)=15x^2+6xy+3y^2$.

Obviously, $V(0,0)=0$. Also, $V(x,y)=6x^2+9x^2+2 \cdot 3x y + y^2 + 2y^2 = 6x^2+2y^2+(3x+y)^2>0$,
$ \forall (x,y) \in R^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$.

From Maple I know that the origin is asymptotically stable.
But I can't show that

$\dot V(x,y) = \displaystyle \frac{\partial V}{\partial x} f(x,y) + \displaystyle \frac{\partial V}{\partial y} g(x,y)=(30x+6y)\sin y + (6x+6y)(-2x-3y) = ... <0$.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Is it mandatory to use the Lyapunov function? You can show local asymptotic stability using the linearization at the origin. Note also that the origin is not a unique equilibrium, there are infinitely many of them.

Comment: Yes I have to use Lyapunov function. Even another one if I can find another one. But I am at this chapter. And I have to work only for the origin.

Answer (score 1):

A Lyapunov function can be found by linearizing the original system at the origin. The linearized system is
$$\tag{1}
\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
\dot x &=& y\\
\dot y&=&-2x-3y
\end{array}\right.
$$
or
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
\dot x\\ \dot y
\end{array}\right)=A
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\y
\end{array}\right),
\quad\mbox{where }
A=\left(\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 1\\ -2& -3
\end{array}\right).
$$
A Lyapunov function for (1) is also a Lyapunov function for the original system (why this is so, is described, for example, [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3430646/problems-finding-a-lyapunov-function/3430701#3430701)). The quadratic form
$$
V(x,y)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}x&y\end{array}\right)
P
\left(\begin{array}{r}x\\y
\end{array}\right)
$$
is a Lyapunov function for (1) if and only if $P>0$ and the matrix $Q=A^TP+PA$ is negative definite. We have
$$
P=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
15 & 3\\ 3& 3
\end{array}\right),\quad
Q=A^TP+PA=\left(\begin{array}{rr}
-12 & 0\\ 0& -12
\end{array}\right),
$$
thus, $V(x,y)$ is a Lyapunov function for the original system.

Comment: Thank you very much !!!