# What is a suitable strict Lyapunov function for this non-linear system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

I have verified using the total energy function that around $(0,0)$ the nonlinear system is stable:

\begin{align}\dot x&=y \\ \dot y &= -x + \beta x^3 - \gamma y \end{align}

where $\beta, \gamma > 0$ are constants. However, I have been trying to find a suitable strict Lyapunov function $V$ but from the expressions I have come up with so far, I cannot definitively deduce that the derivative is less than zero (If I use linearization, then $(0,0)$ is an asymptotically stable sink. I have tried the classical $V = x^2 + y^2$ and tried changing up the coefficients and exponents so that I can have some cancellations of the odd terms. It has been several hours now and still no luck. Any hints will be much appreciated. Moreover, the total energy function that I use for this system is $H(x,y) = \frac{y^2}{2} + \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{\beta x^4}{4}$.

Answer (score 2):

A Lyapunov function can be obtained from the linearized system.
The linearized system is
$$\dot x= y,$$
$$\dot y=-x - \gamma y$$
or
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}\dot x\\\dot y\end{array}\right)=
A \left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right),
$$
where
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{rr}0&1\\-1&-\gamma
\end{array}\right).
$$
Solving the Lyapunov equation $A^TP+PA=-Q$, where $P$ is an unknown matrix,
$Q$ is any positive-definite matrix, one can obtain the solution $P$,
which can be used to construct the Lyapunov function
$$
V(x,y)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}x&y\end{array}\right)
P
\left(\begin{array}{r}x\\y
\end{array}\right).
$$
For example,
$$
Q=\left(\begin{array}{rr}2&0\\0&2
\end{array}\right)
$$
gives us
$$
P=\left(\begin{array}{cc}\frac2{\gamma}+\gamma&1\\1&\frac2{\gamma}
\end{array}\right).
$$
Thus, one of the possible Lyapunov functions is
$$
V(x,y)=\left( \frac2{\gamma}+\gamma\right)x^2+2xy+\frac2{\gamma}y^2.
$$

Comment: I don't think this actually works for nonlinear system. If you take $\dot V$, there will be odd terms that is in the expression i.e $\dot V = - 2(x^2 + y^2) + 2 \beta x^4 + \frac{4 \beta}{\gamma } x^3 y$.

Comment: @Dong Le This works, see this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3430646/problems-finding-a-lyapunov-function

Comment: @Dong Le The terms with $x^4$ and $x^3y$ do not affect the sign of $\dot V$ in some neighborhood of the origin.